# I18n dropdown selection in rails 3, internationalizing and getting ID value inside value=""

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, drop-down-menu, selection

Im trying to be able to internationalize strings from an array to populate a drop down selection form field. Below I posted code from a google blogpost ( link with credits included)

What I would like to do is

- have value="1", thus having the integer inside the value instead of the text ( with current option the text is inserted in the value also
- I want this cause I have profile table with colums like education:integer. Im confused if this is the best way to saving data but thought it would be since a single integer takes less space in the DB
- Any comments on below provided code and solution? Is there a better way to do this?

I have a country list wich I have inserted in my DB like DataCountrys *but* this is not easily translated and I think I have to follow described below code to make that more maintainable and translatable thus removing a database table for each and every single little list (drop down values ) I have in my app.

Hope someone can clarifies above thanks in advanche!

I followed the suggestions on this google groups post:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rails-i18n/mHs7Z_PO6xw

```
en:
  job_categories:
    undergraduate: Undergraduate student
    graduate: Graduate student
    predoctoral: Pre-doctoral student
    postdoctoral: Postdoctoral student
    associate_prof: Asociate professor
    assistent_prof: Assistant professor
    research_prof: Research professor
    technician: Technician
```

And in your model:

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base

```
  def translated_job_category
    I18n.t(job_category, :scope => :job_categories)
  end
```

end

In your helper:

```
module JobsHelper
  def job_categories
    I18n.t(:job_categories).map { |key, value| [ value, key ] }
  end
end
```

And in your view:

```
<%= f.select :job_category, job_categories %>
```

The helper method creates an array that the select-helper understands.
It saves shortened keys ("undergraduate", "graduate", etc) in the
database, as some sort of enumerable. Be sure to keep those the same
in all languages.

When you want to show which job category an object has, you can do
@job.translated_job_category to get the translated value back.